# How to reload particular partial value with response from rails api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I have set up a rails api and it only response in the following format which is done through the serializer:

```
data: { user_name: 'Test User' }
```

And on the view side, I have got the following partial:

```
.user-change
 = render partial: 'test_user', locals: {user_name: current_user.name}
```

What would be the correct way to change the user_name as per the API response from the following successful ajax request?

```
 $("#change-me").click(function() {
  var user_id;
  user_id = $("#user_id").val();

 $.ajax({
    url: "/api/v1/user/change/" + user_id,
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
      {
        user_id: user_id,
      }
    }),
    success: function(res, status, xhr) {
      let response = res.data;
      let userName = response.user_name;

      // Update user_name after this event on the partial?
      }
    },
    error: function(res) {
    }
  });
})
```

Partial code: `_test_user.html.haml`

```
.col-md-9
 %p= "Hi! This is the request change from #{user_name}."
```

Comment: Include your partial code too, please

Comment: @AndreyMakovenko Done